# Angular 6 Reading empty input value

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am getting a value from PHP server to angular 6 through HttpClient, and this value is sent to a `formControlInput` to be set as a default value:

```
<mat-form-field color="warn">
    <input matInput formControlName="unit_type" 
    placeholder="Unit type" value="{{unit_type}}">
</mat-form-field>
```

I am saving the same value into a variable, to compare it to the value of the input so I can detect a change, to know whether I activate the update button or not:

```
this.unit_type = data['unit_info'][0]['unit_type'];
```

Consoling this variable is showing properly, and the value is displayed inside the input.

Now when I get the value of it again like the following:

```
unit_type_upd = this.formGroup.controls['unit_type'].value;
console.log(unit_type_upd);
```

It shows me empty value, but when I change it, it will detect the change, and make the comparing process.

Why `unit_type_upd` is not getting the value displayed inside the input on component load ?

Comment: how are you setting default value?

Comment: No, I am just posting the value from database into the input, then trying to read it using script above.

Comment: No default values are set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Angular Reactive Form` you shouldn't bind data to properties like

```
value="{{unit_type}}"
```

The correct way is this in your component

```
this.formGroup.controls['unit_type'].setValue(this.unit_type)
```

You can set default value when you create your `FormControl` like this

```
new FormControl('default value', [Validators.required]);
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks. And how to set a predefined value of `mat-select` options ?

Answer (score 1):

`value` attributes shouldn't be used in Angular : they're very confusing.

In your case, you indeed set a default value : but you set only the value of the HTML input itslef, no the one of Angular !

To fix the default value, you must do it a form group creation :

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  unit_type: 'default value here'
});
```

If you want to store the first value of your form, store it once your form has been created :

```
this.defaultValue = this.formGroup.value;
```

You can now use the reset method to reset it :

```
this.formGroup.reset(this.defaultValue);
```

And if you want to check if the value has changed, you don't need to compare two values ; simply check the form status ! (either `dirty` or `touched`, see what suits you best)

Here is your HTML :

```
<mat-form-field color="warn">
    <input matInput formControlName="unit_type" placeholder="Unit type">
</mat-form-field>
```